# Relative cocompletion of a category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monads

$\newcommand{\k}{\mathbf k}$
$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal A}$
$\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal B}$
$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal C}$
I'm wondering if anyone knows a reference for the following construction: let $\k$ be a field, say, and assume for convenience everything below is $\k$-linear, and that every category is essentially small. Hereafter "right exact" means "which commutes with finite colimits".

Let $\A$ be a finitely cocomplete category, and $\B$ be an arbitrary (still $\k$-linear and essentially small) category. Suppose we are given a functor
$$
\iota :\A \longrightarrow \B$$
which I'm happy to assume essentially surjective if that helps. Define the relative $\A$-cocompletion of $\B$ to be a category $\B_\A$ equipped with a functor $\nu:\B\rightarrow \B_\A$, universal for the following properties:

1. $\B_\A$ is finitely cocomplete
2. for any finitely cocomplete $\C$, restriction along $\nu$ induces a natural equivalence between: (a) right exact functors $\B_\A \rightarrow \C$ and (b) just functors $\B \rightarrow \C $ such that the composition $\A \rightarrow \B \rightarrow \C$ is right exact.

In words, I want to complete $\B$ under finite colimit, without duplicating those already existing in the image of $\A$. If $\A$ is $Vect$ this should just be the free finite cocompletion.

Remember that the finite cocompletion of $\B$ is the full-subcategory of (linear) presheaves on $\B$ which are finite colimits of representables. I believe $\B_\A$ is then the full subcategory of that, of those presheaves having the property that their restriction along $\iota$ is representable. An example which is an inspiration for this definition is the construction of the category of modules over a monad, from the category of free modules, see e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Moore+category#AsColimitCompletionOfKleisliCategory.

I'm in the process of checking that myself, and it's probably just formal, but I would much rather have a reference where it's done properly.

Comment: I don't have a reference for this particular construction, but I think it is an instance of a general notion: a (2-categorical) [semifinal lift](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+lift) of the unary sink $U({\cal A}) \to \cal B$, where $U$ is the forgetful functor from finitely-cocomplete categories to all categories.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, I wasn't aware of that notion. I should add that though I'd like to have an explicit construction, what I really care about apart from the mere exists of that thing is whether $\nu$ is fully faithful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a special case of the general construction of cocompletions that preserve existing colimits. The general statement can be found as Theorem 6.23 of Kelly's *Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory*, and more explicitly as Proposition 11.4 and Theorem 11.5 of Fiore's *Enrichment and Representation Theorems for Categories of Domains and Continuous Functions* (in the case of small cocompletions, though the result is easily modified to work with a class of colimits instead). In summary, for classes $\Phi, \Psi$ of colimits for which the small category $\mathbf B$ is $\Phi$-cocomplete, there is a conservative $\Psi$-cocompletion $\widehat {\mathbf B}_\Phi$ of $\mathbf B$ preserving the $\Phi$-colimits. This means that the restriction of the (restricted) Yoneda embedding $\mathbf B \to \widehat {\mathbf B}_\Phi$ is $\Phi$-cocontinuous and exhibits a bijection between $\Phi$-cocontinuous functors $\mathbf B \to \mathbf C$ into cocomplete categories $\mathbf C$, and $\Phi$- and $\Psi$-cocontinuous functors $\widehat {\mathbf B}_\Phi \to \mathbf C$. Explicitly, $\widehat {\mathbf B}_\Phi$ is the subcategory of the category of presheaves on $\mathbf B$ which are $\Psi$-colimits of representables taking $\Phi$-cocones to limiting $\Phi$-cones.

In your setting, take $\Phi$ to be the class of colimits in the image of $\iota : \mathbf A \to \mathbf B$, and take $\Psi$ to be the class of finite colimits. Then $\widehat {\mathbf B}_\Phi$ is exactly the finite cocompletion of $\mathbf B$ relative to $\iota$.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful ! Just to be clear: are you saying the description I sketched in my question is correct ? Also, I'm a bit unclear on whether your construction requires, say, $\iota$ to reflect finite colimits. E.g. I'm not, I think, making the assumption that the image in $B$ of a diagram in $A$ has a colimit in $B$, nor am I assming this colimit is the image of the one computed in $A$.

Comment: @Adrien: if I'm not misunderstanding your description, I think it is not correct. For instance, take $\iota$ to be the identity on $B$. Then the finite colimits of representables of $B$ form the cocompletion under finite colimits, which ignores all existing finite colimits in $B$. In answer to your second question, you ought not to need any requirement on $\iota$, since $\iota$ itself is not crucial: the only important data is which colimits are in the image of $\iota$.

Comment: Yes, but then I suggest to take those that become representable upon restriction along $\iota$, so in the case $A=B$ and $\iota=id$ it will give back $B$ as it should, i think ? For your second point then could you clarify what you mean exactly by "the class of colimits in the image of $\iota$" ? Do you actually mean finite diagrams valued in the image of $\iota$ ? Sorry if I'm being daft.

Comment: @Adrien: I think I misunderstood what you meant initially. But in this case, say that $B$ has only some finite colimits, and take $\iota$ to be the identity. Then $B_A = B$, but this doesn't have all finite colimits, so is not correct. By "the class of colimits in the image of $\iota$", I mean the diagrams with colimits in $B$ that arise by postcomposing diagrams with colimits in $A$ by $\iota$.

Comment: Sure, but $A$ is assumed to be finitely cocomplete, so if $\iota$ is the identity then so is $B$ :) Thanks for clarifying, that makes sense.

Comment: @Adrien: ah, of course!